# php passwords in a txt file as database

Tags: php, database, text, passwords, flat-file

I've got this login code (I'm conscious it is really unsafe).

How could I store multiple passwords in a .txt file?

```
   <?php 

$passwords = file('pass.txt');


# Check for session timeout, else initiliaze time
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 < time()) {
        session_destroy(); } }
else {
    $_SESSION['pass']="" ;  $_SESSION['timeout']=time(); }

# Store POST data in session variables
if (isset($_POST["pass"])) {
    $_SESSION['pass']=hash('sha256',$_POST['pass']) ; }

# Check Login Data. Password is hashed (SHA256). In this case it is 'admin'.
$flag = 0;
foreach ($passwords as $pass) {
    if ($pass == $_SESSION['pass']) {
      $flag = 1;
    }
}

if ($flag == 1) {
echo 'session';}
else {
    echo'<form method="POST" action=""><input type="password" name="pass"></form>';}

?>
```

This is pass.txt, from which I want to read the passwords

```
65e84be33532fb784c48129675f9eff3a682b27168c0ea744b2cf58ee02337c5
5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
```

Comment: Why not store them in a database rather then a .txt file? Surely storing makes more sense??

Comment: OK, it was only because I'm completely ignorant of databses. Could you tell me how to do it in sqlite3?

Comment: I cannot do lite, but I can add an answer wth mysqli for php if you like?

Comment: Let's see if it can be done with flat file. Thanks anyway XXX

Comment: @Kathlyn u will have to store in the database only

Comment: any chance you can work with MySQL rather than sqlite3? Plus, I highly suggest against `$_SESSION['pass']` storing passwords in sessions; ever heard about sessions hijacking? I hope you don't find out the hard way. Storing your passwords in a text file for one thing, and as already stated, is unsafe, especially if you haven't protected that text file in `.htaccess`. Take the initiative to learning databases; I have years ago and used to do what you are wanting to do now.

Answer (score 1):

I will start with, **yes** - you are very correct that it's unsafe. Especially if the passwords are stored in a txt file accessible to the web.

I am guessing that the password doesn't have to match with a username, so you could simply store the passwords either in a plain txt file, or (for slightly more security) store them as an array in an included PHP file (which wouldn't be displayed as plain text if it's location is compromised).

For plain text, read the file into an array

`$passwords = file('path/to/file.txt');`

Or include the PHP file with the array (which for the sake of this example is stored in an array called $passwords.

Then set a flag and run through the array checking and replace the final condition with one that tests the flag.

```
$flag = 0;
foreach ($passwords as $pass) {
    if ($pass == $_SESSION['pass']) {
      $flag = 1;
    }
}

if ($flag == 1) {
echo 'session';}
else {
    echo'<form method="POST" action=""><input type="password" name="pass"></form>';}
```

Comment: Looks good, as it doesnt work, modified the question for you to see what I'm doing. any mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I personally not recommend you to store password in .txt , but still i may help you .. You want to store multiple passwords using file handling you can do this using json functions ..

```
function writeToFile($filename, $msg)
 { 
   $msgArray=array();
   if(file_exists($filename))
        {
        $arrMsg=json_decode(file_get_contents($filename),true);
        foreach ($arrMsg as $ob)
          {
             array_push($msgArray,$ob);
          }
        unlink($filename);
        }
   array_push($msgArray,$msg);
   $msgArrayJSON=json_encode($msgArray);
   // open file
   $fd = fopen($filename, "a");
   // write string
   fwrite($fd, $msgArrayJSON. PHP_EOL);
   // close file
   fclose($fd);
}
```

And by using the above function you may add user like

```
writeToFile('user.json', array("username"=>$id,"password"=>$name));
```

Finally , you could get users from file as below

```
$user_array=json_decode(file_get_contents('user.json'),true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP functions fopen() and fwrite() like this:

```
<?php
    /* the a is used to place the writer at the end of the file, w would place it
    at the beginning of the file overwriting already stored data*/
    $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "My Mother\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    // or direct input
    fwrite($myfile, "My Sister\n");
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Notice the \n to go to the next line in the text file.

Ofcourse a database would be the best way to go, but if you want to do it with text files I highly recommand you to still try to create some structure. Have a look at XML or JSON.

Comment: Sidenote: The `w` switch in `fopen("newfile.txt", "w")` will overwrite any previously written content. I'm pretty sure she wants to append.

Comment: You're right, I changed it. I quickly copied it, forgetting about the mode.